# how to attach an image to a custom post type in wordpress using just code

Tags: images, code

I'm dynamically creating a custom post type in code (not in the editor) and I have an image I want to attach to my custom post type as a post thumbnail, and have it resized, etc. How do I do that. I'm successfully creating the custom post type using wp_insert_post().

I've looked at wp_save_image(), wp_save_image_file(), load_image_to_edit(), get_attached_file() and others, but they all seem to require an image in $_POST. I also looked at wp_insert_attachment() and update_attached_file() which seemed promising, but were not image centric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP 3.1 introduces [`set_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail) function, that sets attachment (that you will need to create first, you seem to be on right track with [`wp_insert_atachment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)) as thumbnail for the post.

Comment: thanks the codex page you referenced for wp_insert_attachment() provided an excellent example. I used to only read codex pages, then recently I started to just read the core code - I guess both are the the best!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you can with wp_insert_post, but you can add the images' URL in the custom field.

`update_post_meta( $post_id,'image_url',$image_url);`